# Get the RSSI on Apple Watch

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, apple-watch, watchos

How do I go about getting the RSSI of my Apple Watch? Core Bluetooth is now supported so we should be good. I can't find any documentation or code that works! I need a helping hand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [CBCentralManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate), you should be able to get that by implementing this method,

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, 
                     didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, 
                     advertisementData: [String : Any], 
                     rssi RSSI: NSNumber)
```